# Can you handle both json and html datatypes in the same ajax call?

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there anyway I can handle both json and html return types when posting jquery ajax:

For example, this ajax call expects html back

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                var $html = "<li class='list-item'>" + response + "</li>";
                $('#a').prepend($html);                           
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
```

but I wanted to modify it so that I can return a json object if there is a model error.  so I can do something like this:

```
success: function (response) {
          if (response.Error){
                 alert(response.Message);   
          } else {
              var $html = "<li class='list-item'>" + response + "</li>";
              $('#a').prepend($html);                           
          }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you first case, just put the html in the `response.Message` field.  It's not uncommon to return html wrapped inside a json object so that a status code can be easily added.